# How to go back to previous view controller of different storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have 2 storyboards say A and B. Storyboard A has multiple view controllers. After some user action I switch from storyboard A to storyboard B. How can I go back to previous storyboard A on clicking back button and go back to same view controller  I  initially came from.

I can't do as given below because I will not have the old navigation stack of A.

```
 let storyboard =  UIStoryboard(name: "A", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as UIViewController!
    presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: are your viewcontrollers embedded in a navigationcontroller?

Comment: Yes they are. Does navigationcontroller remains same even after storyboard change ?

Comment: see my answer below...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if your viewcontrollers are embedded in a navigationcontroller you can do the following:

**to move from storyboard A to storyboard B**

```
let storyboard =  UIStoryboard(name: "B", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as UIViewController!
navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

**to get back from storyboard B to storyboard A**

```
navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

(of course the the initial viewcontroller in storyboard B should not be a navigationcontroller but a regular viewcontroller)

Comment: This is not working. My navigation controller only has one view controller in it. That is initial view controller of storyboard B

Comment: It is a company project so I can't share it.

Comment: I removed the navigation controller at the start of B and made regular view controller as initial view controller. Not working in that case as well.

Comment: can you maybe show a screenshot of your viewcontroller hierarchy?

Comment: It was not working initially because I was changing storyboard from a modal view controller.

Answer (score 9):

The "Back" button should be linked to something like this:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: In Xcode 9, Swift 4, it is: `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

Answer (score 1):

For XCODE 9 Swift 4

```
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code.. when you want to go back to previous one

```
navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Comment: In Xcode 9, Swift 4, it is: `navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`